# Nightwatch/Chromedriver with Android. Arguments for chrome are completely ignored

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-app, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to run some nightwatch tests in my android emulator. My configuration for android in my nightwatch.json looks like follows:

```
"android" : {
      "selenium_port" : 9515,
      "selenium_host" : "localhost",
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true,
        "chromeOptions": {
              "androidPackage": "com.android.chrome",
              "args": ["--disable-web-security", "--no-first-run"]
          }
      }
    }
```

The test runs without issues. But I'm always seeing the "First Run Experience" page in each run. Also it is always checking the SSL certificates event when I have set the --disable-web-security flag. Those flags work with Desktop version of Chrome.

I guess this is not an issue with Nightwatch itself. So  maybe other implementations of selenium+android would work.

Addtionally, **I'm not allowed to use Appium**.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong? Have you faced the same issue?

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use Appium? It is actually running a local Server and becoming the default way to test mobile browsers in Android.

Comment: If you take a look at this use of Appium, you will find it all runs local http://www.shaneofalltrades.com/2016/08/26/Mobile-Web-Testing-Using-Nightwatchjs-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this spesific case, but passing args to Chrome via the conf file should not include the '--' in the beginning.

So, args: ["some-option"] instead of args: ["--some-option"] makes the difference in my setups.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below configuration for mobile emulation in the Chrome web browser:

```
"desiredCapabilities": {
            "browserName": "chrome",
            "javascriptEnabled": true,
            "acceptSslCerts": true,
    
            "chromeOptions": {
              "mobileEmulation": { "deviceName" : "Galaxy S5"},
              "args": [
                "disable-web-security"
              ]
            }
          },
```